# AngularJS interpolation issue with translate service

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-interpolate

I have this ternary operator in my html (working correctly)

```
{{ qp.QP_TRANSFERS === '1' ? qp.QP_TRANSFER_TYPE_NAME + ' transfer' : 'No transfer' }}
```

I'm using translation service from json objects. This is an example of en_US.json file:

```
"myquotes": {
"PAGETITLE": "My quotes",
"DESCRIPTION": "List of all your asked quotes",
"packages": {
    "label": {
      "SEARCH": {
        "TITLE": "Package quotes",
        "DESCRIPTION": "Search by any column",
      "QUOTE": "Quote",
      "ADULTS": "Adults",
      "MINORS": "Minors",
      "TRANSFER": "transfer",
      "NOTRANSFER": "No transfer"
      }
    },
  }
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
{{ 'myquotes.packages.label.ADULTS' | translate }}
```

Is there a way to use this service in my ternary example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/irfCPL?p=preview) you have a working example of what I understand you are looking for.
You basically you have use parenthesis to wrap your ternary expression `( ... )` before you use the `translate` filter, but I recommend you to put that logic inside a function on your controller to have a more readable template:

```
      <p>{{ ('myquotes.packages.label.SEARCH.' + (qp.QP_TRANSFERS === '1' ? 'TRANSFER' : 'NOTRANSFER')) | translate}}</p>
```

Or:

```
 <p>{{ getLabel(qp.QP_TRANSFERS) | translate}}</p>
```

Other option could be to use the [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) directive to initilize the full string Key once into a variable and then use the `translate`filter against that variable, something like this:

```
<p 
   ng-init="LABEL = 'myquotes.packages.label.SEARCH.' +
                    (qp.QP_TRANSFERS === '1' ? 'TRANSFER' : 'NOTRANSFER')">
  {{ LABEL | translate}}
</p>
```

Comment: This was so easy but I couldn't get there. Thank you so much. I'm trying and accepting the answer after thant. Muchas gracias.